# How to get the count of the find results in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a code to count the number of occurrence of the find results, the problem i am facing is., if the find data is more than 255 characters the code is returning count as '0' although we have some matches, where as for those find data which are less than 255 the code is properly working and fetching the right count.
Can anyone please rectify the issue, below is the code.

```
Sub CommentCount()

Dim CSAT_Comments As Workbook
Dim comment As Worksheet
Dim match As Worksheet
Dim CommentString As String
Dim MatchRow As Integer


Set CSAT_Comments = ActiveWorkbook
Set comment = CSAT_Comments.Worksheets("Qualitative Analysis_2018 Cycle") 
Set match = CSAT_Comments.Worksheets("Consolidated Comments") 

Dim CommentRange As Range
match.Range("A2").Select
Dim CRange As Range
Dim DuplicateCount As Integer

Set CommentRange = match.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)) 'Defining the range

For Each CRange In CommentRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)


CommentString = Left(CRange.Value, 255) 'Store the first 225 characters of the string
MatchRow = CRange.Row 'To get the row number of the respective comments


With comment

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

.Activate
Columns("AK:BL").Select 'Range which needs to be searched

DuplicateCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("AK:BL"), "" & CommentString) ' To get the count of find result and here is where i am getting the problem when the search string is >255


With match
.Activate
.Range("B" & MatchRow) = DuplicateCount 'Paste the count in the against respective commments

End With

End With



Next CRange


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
CommentString = Left(CRange.Value, 254) & "*" 'Store the first 254 characters of the string, leaving the 255th character for final asterisk
```

Comment: I am getting an error as "Unable to get the CountIf propertyof the worksheetFunction class".
I am getting the above error when there search string is more than 255 characters, if it is less your changes is working

Comment: as per you code (`CommentString = Left(CRange.Value, 255)`), I assumed `CommentString` is less then 255 characters

Comment: just use your code as you showed in your question except for the `Count.If` line where you'd use my answer

Comment: you might have to make CommentString  a max of 254 chars as there is an asterisk pinned on the back end.

Comment: @Jeeped, you're right. I'll edit my answer. thank you